# OutOfBoundsException When Calling Return For A Method JAVA

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

i'll get straight to the chase. If a user wants to read another file they must type r in the menu, then they are thrown with a return readFile(); method which takes them to the top of the program and asks them the same question it did at the beggining when they first ran this program. Only issue is when you type R or Default it throws an OutOFBoundsException. BTW It is Reading a CSV file

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1000
    at studentrecs.StudentRecs.in(StudentRecs.java:71)
    at studentrecs.StudentRecs.readFile(StudentRecs.java:55)
    at studentrecs.StudentRecs.menu(StudentRecs.java:97)
    at studentrecs.StudentRecs.main(StudentRecs.java:33)
Java Result: 1
```

/

```
     public static Boolean readFile(String filename) throws IOException { //Constructor for filename
        try {
            Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("Type R To Read a File or Type Default for the default file");
            user = userInput.nextLine();
            if (user.equalsIgnoreCase("r")) {
                user = userInput.nextLine();
            }
            filename = user;
            if (user.equalsIgnoreCase("default")) {
                filename = "newreg2.csv";
            }

            Scanner input = new Scanner(new FileReader(filename));
            while (input.hasNext()) {
                in(input.nextLine());
                numstu++;
            }
            input.close();
            return true;

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return false;
    }


public static void in(String reader) {
        String splitter[];
        splitter = reader.split(",");
        stu[numstu] = new StuRec();
        stu[numstu].studentID = splitter[0];
        stu[numstu].lastName = splitter[1];
        stu[numstu].firstName = splitter[2];
        stu[numstu].phoneNumber = splitter[3];
        stu[numstu].courseCode = splitter[4];
        stu[numstu].periodNumber = Integer.parseInt(splitter[5]);  // parseInt turns a string of digits into an integer
        stu[numstu].mark = Integer.parseInt(splitter[6]);
    }

 public static boolean menu() throws IOException {
    String choice;
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("=============================================");
    System.out.println("Type R To Read Another File");
    System.out.println("Type L To Print all File Records");
    System.out.println("Type AA To Print The Average Of All The Marks");
    System.out.println("Type X To Exit The Program");
    choice = userInput.nextLine();
    double average = 0.0; // declare average

        if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("L")) {
            for (int i = 0; i < numstu; i++) {
           System.out.println(stu[i].lastName + ", " + stu[i].firstName + ", " + stu[i].studentID + ", " + stu[i].phoneNumber + ", " + stu[i].courseCode + ", " + stu[i].periodNumber + ", " + stu[i].mark);
            }
            }else if  (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("R")){
              return readFile(filename);  
        } else if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("AA")) {
            for (int i = 0; i < numstu; i++) {
              average += stu[i].mark; // keep adding to average

            }
        }else if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("X")) {
            for (int i = 0; i < numstu; i++) {
                System.exit(i);
            }
        }else if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("AC"))    {


        } else {System.err.println("Unknown Key Try Again...");  
        }

    // divide by zero protection
    if ( choice.equalsIgnoreCase("AA") && numstu > 0 ) {
        average = average/numstu;  // compute the average. Always use the size in terms of a variable whenever possible.
        System.out.println(average); // as noted below, if this is an integer value, < #of students computations will eval to 0.
    }
    else if (!choice.equalsIgnoreCase("AA") && numstu < 0) {
        System.out.println("Oops! No Marks To Calculate! :(");
    }
    return menu();
}

}
```

Comment: Another day, another java index out of bounds exception question without a stacktrace.

Comment: You've got a method called `in` that you haven't shown us.  Can  you show us please?

Comment: please show us the stacktrace, in order for us to know what line throws it.

Comment: Where have you declared and initialised `stu`?  How many entries does it have?  How many lines in your file?  And does every line of your file have at least 6 commas, with no blank lines anywhere?

Comment: in another class stu has been declared, there is 1000 lines exactly and 6 commas no blank spaces or blank spots anywhere

Comment: what is at line 71 inside the in method ?

Comment: stu[numstu] = new StuRec();

Answer (score 0):

It looks like EITHER you have initialised `numstu` to start at 1, OR you have more than 1000 lines in your file.

The effect of either of these errors would be that you eventually attempt to write data to entry 1000 of `stu`.  But since you've initialised `stu` with 1000 entries, numbered from 0 to 999, this gives your error.

You should make sure that `numstu` is initially 0, not 1.

And next time you post a question, post ALL of your code, not just the parts where you think the error might be.  It's very difficult for most people to find bugs in code that they can't see.